# Styling body text in a href mailto link

Tags: html, css

I have an hyperlink which has a `mailto` link and I am specifying the subject and body text in the hyperlink itself. So when the user clicks on the hyperlink, his default email client application will be opened with the To, Subject and body text pre-populated in it.

I want to know how I can apply css formatting technique in the `body` text of it something like `font` names, `font color` etc.

Can anyone give me any idea on this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Unauthorized access</title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
        <!-- bootstrap 3.0.2 -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- font Awesome -->
        <link href="../css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Theme style -->
    </head>
    <body class="skin-blue">
        <!-- header logo: style can be found in header.less -->
        <div>
            <!-- Right side column. Contains the navbar and content of the page -->
            <aside class="right-side" style="margin-left:0">
                <section class="content">
                    <div class="error-page" style="margin: 0">
                        <div class="error-content" style="width:100%">
                            <h3><i class="fa fa-warning text-yellow"></i> You are not authorized to view the content.</h3>       <br>
                            <p style="width:75%; text-align:center;margin-left:15%">
                                Please make sure you have the access to the server or contact support team at <a href="mailto:username@domain.com?subject=Unable&nbsp;to&nbsp;access&nbsp;server&body=Hi,%0D%0A%0D%0AMy&nbsp;user&nbsp;account&nbsp;does&nbsp;not&nbsp;have&nbsp;access&nbsp;for&nbsp;the&nbsp;server.%0D%0A%0D%0ARequest&nbsp;you&nbsp;to&nbsp;kindly&nbsp;provide&nbsp;access&nbsp;to&nbsp;server.">username@domain.com</a>.
                            </p>
                        </div><!-- /.error-content -->
                    </div><!-- /.error-page -->
                </section><!-- /.content -->
            </aside><!-- /.right-side -->
        </div><!-- ./wrapper -->
    </body>
</html>
```

On clicking the email hyperlink, the below message will be shown in the email content.

[image: Sample]

I want to apply css formatting to the content highlighted in the red box.

Comment: can you show us your code? if you could create fiddle, it would be great

Comment: You can only use inline styling. This means your linked stylesheet won't work.  To give you an example .. `<aside class="right-side" style="margin-left:0">` will become `<aside style="float: right; margin-left: 0">` . Even so..probably won't work because every client has it's own styling that you need to overwrite with your inline styling...

Answer (score 4):

You can't change/modify CSS  of a mail client through a `<a href="mail to:mail@example.com"></a>` .

They have their own CSS styles and this would be a security issue

Comment: What do you mean by "they have their own css style"? There certainly is some common standard as I'm able to send colorized mail that gets received correctly in many clients.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Dippas' answer...

According to the [Mailto specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt), you can add whatever arbitrary headers you want to your mailto link. This means you could add `&Content-Type=text/html` to the url to indicate it's an HTML message, in which case it should parse your HTML and CSS like a normal HTML email.

However the spec also states that the only headers that should be **relied upon** are the subject and body headers.

> The creator of a mailto URL cannot expect the resolver of a URL to
>   understand more than the "subject" and "body" headers. Clients that
>   resolve mailto URLs into mail messages should be able to correctly
>   create RFC 822-compliant mail messages using the "subject" and "body"
>   headers.

In other words, you can try it, but don't expect it to work for everyone. If this is for public use, just forget about it, stick to plaintext.